# Compare file names of two directories and move matched files to 3rd directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 folders. 1)Content 2) Shared 3)MoveHere
I have 50 txt files in "Content"  folder and 300 text files in "Shared" folder.
here, names of 50 txt files in "Content" folder matches with names of files in "Shared" folder.
What we need here is, move those matched files from "Shared" folder to MoveHere folder.

I tried below code, but it did not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import shutil


# Get current working directory
CD = os.getcwd()
SUD = '/D:/TestScript/shareduser/'
DEST = '/D:/TestScript/MoveHere/'

# Get a list of files in the current working directory
for file_CD in os.listdir(CD):
    file_name_in_Content = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(file_CD)[0])
    #print('CWD '+ file_name_in_Content)
    for file_SUD in os.listdir(SUD):
        file_name_in_SharedUser = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(file_SUD)[0])
        if file_name_in_Content == file_name_in_SharedUser:
            SRC_FULL_PATH = SUD + "/" + file_SUD
            DEST_FULL_PATH = DEST + "/" + file_SUD
            shutil.move(SRC_PATH, DEST_PATH)
print ("\nDone")
```

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: `shutil.move(SRC_PATH, DEST_PATH)` should be `shutil.move(SRC_FULL_PATH, DEST_FULL_PATH)`

Comment: `'/D:/TestScript/shareduser/'` this isn't a valid windows path. Check raw strings and `os.path.join`, that will save you a lot of trouble with slashes.